# Swagger 2.0: How to specify an input parameter of type 'object'

Tags: parameters, swagger

Using Swagger 2.0 I am trying to specify an input parameter of type object:

code snippet:

```
paths:
  '/thingies/{thingy_id}.json':
    put:
      summary: Update an existing thingy
      description: Updates an existing thingy
      parameters:
        - name: thingy_id
          description: ID of the thingy to update
          in: path
          required: true
          type: integer
        - name: translation
          description: Name and Locale for new translation
          in: formData
          type: object
          properties:
            name:
              type: string
            locale:
              type: string
```

However the validator is complaining about the `type: object` part.

How ought I correctly specify my input parameters?

Answer (score 12):

Okay, thanks to the input from @ron I have worked out the solution.  Yes I need to use `body` instead of `formData` but even then it didn't validate, complaining about `type: object`. But if I define the object first then `$ref` it then it all works.  The following code does validate.

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: '1'
  title: Thingy Service
  description: Everyone loves their thingy
schemes:
  - http
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json

definitions:
  localisation:
    type: object
    required:
      - name
      - locale
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
      locale:
        type: string

paths:
  '/thingies/{thingy_id}.json':
    put:
      summary: Update an existing thingy
      description: Updates an existing thingy
      parameters:
        - name: thingy_id
          description: ID of the thingy to update
          in: path
          required: true
          type: integer
        - name: translation
          description: Name and Locale for new translation
          in: body
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/localisation'
      responses:
        204:
          description: No data
        404:
          description: Thingy not found
```

Answer (score 9):

Swagger allows for object inputs only as body parameters.

The reason for that relates to the way content is serialized which depends on the `Content-Type` header (`produces` in Swagger). That header relates to the payload as a whole.

When passing form parameters, you'd use one of two mime types: `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. While the former does allow you to specify a mime type per part, Swagger currently does not support such a definition. There's an open ticket on it to allow it in a future version of the spec.

Currently, when specifying form parameters, you can only specify primitives or arrays of primitives.

Comment: If I change `formData` to `body` the code still won't validate.  Any suggestions?

Comment: It didn't validate because you need to contain the definition inside the `schema` property, but I see you've got that figured out. The structure of `body` parameters is different in that sense from other parameters *because* it allows for a full schema definition.

Comment: yes, thanks. I got it with a bit of trial and error :-)

Comment: what is the ticket number?